# Sinus curve with elbows / round steps?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Can I calculate a sinus function that has kind of **elbows** / **round steps** in it ?
Or if I could get hold on the second curve. I need one of these functions for some graphical design. How would the formula for the periodic curve look like ? Can I use it with simple mathematics ?

*(It will be applied to a computer program. So it might contain a few steps and provisional results)*

1)

[image]

Sorry, both drawn in **`Paint XP`**.

2)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first graph looks rather like $\sin(x) - \sin(x)^3/3$.

[image]